# special key wrench for spin-down filter's brass 3/4" MNPT fitting that lacks wrench flats?

Tags: plumbing, fitting, hand-tools, terminology

We've had a lot of sediment in the water after this past month's flooding. Water pressure also jumped to 100psi. The Water Authority had to shut down a plant and reroute the system through some disused conduits. So I bought an overpressure valve, a little spin-down filter, and a two-stage point-of-entry filtration device and am now working through what fittings will best enable individual components to be removed and serviced.

The plumbing in the house is 3/4" copper. The spin-down filter has multiple ways to connect. It has 1" MNPT threads. Inside each of those threads is a 3/4" FNPT thread. There is also a threaded coupling option that fits over the 1" male thread; it has a 3/4 MNPT brass fitting that emerges from the coupling's hex nut; those 3/4 MNPT brass fittings would protrude on either side of the filter like ears.  Inside the coupling's hex nut the seal is made with a flexible washer.

The 3/4 MNPT brass fitting has no wrench flats (see picture) but there are two little tabs inside it. I assume those tabs are meant to be used with a key wrench of some kind, to let you tighten  a 3/4 FNPT fitting onto the brass fitting? If that's right, is there a name for that kind of key wrench?

[image: brass fitting without wrench flats]
[image: spin down filter with fittings]

Comment: I believe you'll find the outside threads are not pipe threads (tapered) but rather straight threads (for the included union fittings) https://sanitaryfittings.us/npt-vs-nps  I'd also check to see if you could sweat copper tubing to the inside of the outside-threaded union fittings. They have that look to them.

Comment: @Ecnerwal : Here is a video showing PEX and Sharkbite-style connections. They want you to use the handle of the supplied wrench to tighten this. But on another matter, the direction-of-spin of the union's nut makes no sense to me around the 30-35 second mark.  https://www.amazon.com/SimPure-Sediment-Reusable-Spindown-Pre-Filter/dp/B082174CB9/ref=sr_1_23?dchild=1&keywords=ispring+spin+down&qid=1632670249&s=hi&sr=1-23

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To unscrew that fitting with the inside knobs or as you said "tabs", try using a "spud wrench" which is a tool used by HVAC people to replace union fittings on cast iron radiators. Your local HVAC company may have one you could borrow for a few minutes.

Answer (score 1):

Well, I have found my socket set had a wide blade that fitted some, but even some large allen keys can fit.

Or cut some flat bar stock and bend for a handle. Lots of options really as it does not need to be stupidly tight, especially as some ptfe would be appropriate.

Comment: And not buy a special tool I'll only ever use once? Are you crazy, man?  :-)

Comment: @mrblint so ptfe was named for you: Pull Tight (it’s) F***** Expensive. :)

Comment: I like your ideas, @mrblint, and would like to subscribe to your newsletter! :D